# Last vs past with past simple

Tags: past-tense

Can last and past be used interchangeably? I have done some research but I cannot find the proper answer and I am still confused.

- He was working for the past 2 months.
- He was working for the last 2 months.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it will do when it is as follows:

```
He was working for the past 2 months.
He was working for the last 2 months.
```

but it won't as

```
He was working for the past 2 months.
He was working for last 2 months.
```

The difference in the latter case is the same as the difference between *next* and *the next* regarding a period of time.